# Unable to get the maven installation path

Tags: java, macos, maven, mvn-repo

I have installed **maven 3.6.0** in my mac using **homebrew**. When I try

```
mvn --version
```

in my terminal, I get the

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-25T05:41:47+11:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.0/libexec
Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_AU, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

But when I try ,

```
whereis mvn
```

I dont receive anything in return? Can someone let me know what I have done wrong in the installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for the installation folder, `mvn --version` shows you the path.

`Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.0/libexec`

Even better, try:

`which mvn`

Reason why `whereis` couldn't return is explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/1252822).

Comment: Yes  I agree , but why doesnt whereis command return me that?

Answer (score 0):

Download the Maven, for example apache-maven-3.x.x-bin.tar.gz. Extracts it,

tar -xvf apache-maven-3.x.x-bin.tar.gz $pwd /Users/mkyong/apache-maven-3.x.x

Copy

2.2 – Set Maven command in environment variable.
Update ~/. bash_profile – create this file if doesn’t exist.

$ vim ~/.bash_profile

Copy

~/.bash_profile

export M2_HOME=/Users/mkyong/apache-maven-3.x.x export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin

Copy

Restart the terminal. Test it.

Then whereis mvn will work

Comment: I have already refered to the MyKong tutorial and it didnt work

Comment: Hi, so you installed first time how , like what are the steps you followed & which Mac version you are using